# Sequelize underscored option not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js

I've been following Ben Awad's tutorials on YouTube. Specifically I'm using `sequelize` to set up a PostgreSQL database as he outlines.

I want to define my fields in camel case and have them converted to snake case as he does in his tutorials, specifically [here](https://youtu.be/DlNVHWo_nq8?list=PLN3n1USn4xlkdRlq3VZ1sT6SGW0-yajjL&t=39), also outlined in the `sequelize` [docs](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-definition.html#configuration). However when I do the same my table fields are not converted to snake case.

Here's a MWE of the code I'm using:

**models/index.js**

```
import Sequelize from 'sequelize';

var sequelize = new Sequelize('dms', 'postgres', 'postgres', {
    dialect: 'postgres', 
    define: {
        underscored: true,
        freezeTableName: true,
    },
});

const models = {
    Appointments: sequelize.import('./appointment'),
};

Object.keys(models).forEach(modelName => {
    if (models[modelName].associate) {
        models[modelName].associate(models);
    }
});

models.sequelize = sequelize;
models.Sequelize = Sequelize;

export default models;
```

From the file above it is my understanding that `define: {underscored: true}` should convert all table fields to snake case, as stated in his tutorial video above.

**models/appointment.js**

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Appointment = sequelize.define("appointment",
        {
            status: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            appointmentStart: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
            },
            appointmentEnd: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
            },
        },
    );

    return Appointment;
};
```

**index.js**

```
import { ApolloServer, gql} from 'apollo-server';
import typeDefs from './schema';
import resolvers from './resolvers';
import models from './models';

const PORT = 8080;

const graphqlEndpoint = '/graphql';

const server = new ApolloServer({
    typeDefs,
    resolvers,
    graphqlPath: graphqlEndpoint
});

models.sequelize.sync({force:true}).then(() =>  {
    server.listen(PORT)
});
```

The output SQL from the above MWE is as follows:

```
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "appointment" CASCADE;
Executing (default): DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "appointment" CASCADE;
Executing (default): CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "appointment" ("id"   SERIAL , "status" VARCHAR(255), "appointmentStart" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, "appointmentEnd" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE, "created_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, "updated_at" TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY ("id"));
Executing (default): SELECT i.relname AS name, ix.indisprimary AS primary, ix.indisunique AS unique, ix.indkey AS indkey, array_agg(a.attnum) as column_indexes, array_agg(a.attname) AS column_names, pg_get_indexdef(ix.indexrelid) AS definition FROM pg_class t, pg_class i, pg_index ix, pg_attribute a WHERE t.oid = ix.indrelid AND i.oid = ix.indexrelid AND a.attrelid = t.oid AND t.relkind = 'r' and t.relname = 'appointment' GROUP BY i.relname, ix.indexrelid, ix.indisprimary, ix.indisunique, ix.indkey ORDER BY i.relname;
```

As can be seen, it does not convert fields such as `appointmentStart` to `appointment_start`.

I have also tried declaring `underscored: true` on the indiviudal models, such as the following:

```
export default (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Appointment = sequelize.define("appointment",
        {
            status: {
                type: DataTypes.STRING
            },
            appointmentStart: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
            },
            appointmentEnd: {
                type: DataTypes.DATE,
            },
        }, { underscored: true }
    );

    return Appointment;
};
```

This too does not work.

I feel like I'm perhaps missing something obvious, or have a fundemental misunderstanding.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What version of Sequelize are you using? I'm guessing v4 or earlier; the `underscored` option only applies to property / column names on v5 or newer.

In Sequelize v4, the only property names which `underscored: true` affects are the generated timestamp properties that Sequelize creates when `timestamps: true` is used; (ie. `createdAt` => `created_at`, `updatedAt` => `updated_at` etc.),

Model columns declared in your `sequelize.define()` don't get converted to snake case, you need to explicitly set the `field` attribute on each camel-case column name in order to achieve this. For your `appointmentStart` column above, this would look like:

```
...
appointmentStart: {
    type: DataTypes.DATE,
    field: 'appointment_start',
},
```